# Get PDF Page Number using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I've been playing with this library with no luck. I want to extract the literal 1196 page below. How can I do it with this library?

[image: PageNum]

Comment: Are you only interested with: [1] getting the literal *1196*, or [2] the PDF page itself? (to extract the text, extract the whole page, etc) You should edit your question to be a more specific and specify **exactly** what you're trying to do once you get [1] or [2].

Comment: hi @kuujinbo, I am interested with 1...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after a few tries, I did manage to get that literal page so I am going to share this. So technically, that literal 1196 is a page label and here's the code to get all those labels:

> ```
>     PdfReader r = new PdfReader(fileName);
>      try
>      {
>         foreach (string s in PdfPageLabels.GetPageLabels(r))
>            Console.WriteLine(s);
>      }
>      catch (Exception ex)
>      {
>         Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
>      }
>      finally
>      {
>         r.Close();
>      }
> ```

Comment: If the pdf file, don't have any Page Labels, it will return null. 
It's ok if using foreach, but if you make any logic, like `PdfPageLabels.GetPageLabels(pdfReader)[0]` make sure to test for nullness before.

@Jojo This is a very specific case, and your 8 years old answer saved my day.